# Subtasks in Local Queue

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

I was reading a book on Parallel Programming by Colin Campbell, when I came across following lines:

> When one of the task factory methods is called from within a thread
>   pool worker thread, the default task scheduler places the new task in
>   that thread’s local task queue. This is a faster operation than
>   placing it in the global queue.

What I deduced from above paragraph, I coded the following thinking that all tasks will be executed by the same worker thread as it was further written in the Book:

> any time you create a task from within another task or from within a
>   thread pool work item, you are performing an operation that is part of
>   some larger computation

```
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Task Id for A task: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

             // subtasks within Global Task 
            var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); Console.WriteLine("Task Id for B task : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); });  
            var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine("Task Id for C task: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); });  
            var t4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); Console.WriteLine("Task Id for D task: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); });  

            Task.WaitAll(t2, t3, t4);
        });
```

But contrary to my expectation, the result turned out as:

**Result:**

Task Id for A task: 1
Task Id for B task: 2
Task Id for D task: 4
Task Id for C task: 3

**Expectation:**

Task Id for A task: 1
Task Id for B task: 1
Task Id for D task: 1
Task Id for C task: 1

Seems like my intuition misleading me! Where did I lose the track?

Comment: You forgot about work stealing, it will likely be in the same section as your first quote. What results do you get if you remove the sleeps and the WaitAll. also task Id != thread Id you are checking the wrong value to see thread sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about work stealing, it will likely be in the same section as your first quote. What results do you get if you remove the sleeps and the WaitAll. also task Id != thread Id you are checking the wrong value to see thread sharing.